# Another div or HTML tag will slide out when user mouses over the button

Tags: html, css, hover, mouseover

I have problem trying to slide out when user hovers the button. I have the code as shown below:

```css
/**
     * CSS3 balancing hover effect
     * Read the tutorial here: http://webbb.be/blog/little-css3-3d-hover-effects/
     */

body {
  background: #f06;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f06, yellow);
  min-height: 100%;
}

.block {
  width: 150px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 350;
}

.block .normal {
  background: gray;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.block .hover {
  margin-top: -48px;
}

.block .hover {
  background: #00aced;
  left: 150px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
}

.block:hover .normal {
  background: #0084b4;
}

.block:hover .hover {
  margin-right: 0;
  display: block;
  transform-origin: top;
  /*
     animation-name: balance;
     animation-duration: 1.5s;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
     animation-delay: 110ms;
     animation-iteration-count: 1;
     animation-direction: alternate;
     */
  animation: balance 1.5s ease-in-out 110ms 1 alternate;
}

@keyframes balance {
  0% {
    margin-top: -48px;
  }
  15% {
    margin-top: -48px;
    transform: rotateY(-50deg);
  }
  30% {
    margin-top: -48px;
    transform: rotateY(50deg);
  }
  45% {
    margin-top: -48px;
    transform: rotateY(-30deg);
  }
  60% {
    margin-top: -48px;
    transform: rotateY(30deg);
  }
  75% {
    margin-top: -48px;
    transform: rotateY(-30deg);
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: -48px;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="normal">
    <span>Follow me...</span>
  </div>
  <a target="_BLANK" class="hover" href="http://twitter.com/benoitboucart" title="My twitter profile">
    on Twitter
  </a>
</div>
```

May I know what should I do to make it slide on the left hand side not shake? I did try a lot of method for example transition: 0.5s ease 0s; and many other, but it does not work. May I know what should I do the make it slide out on the left hand slide?

Comment: Anybody have the answer for that?

Answer (score 2):

Check it out. I have explained the code by commenting is css.

```css
/**
 * CSS3 balancing hover effect
 * Read the tutorial here: http://webbb.be/blog/little-css3-3d-hover-effects/
 */

body {
  background: #f06;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f06, yellow);
  min-height: 100%;
}

.block {
  width: 150px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 350;
}

.block .normal {
  background: gray;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.block .hover {
  background: #00aced;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;/*add this to make it position absolutely right to the parent so that it can slide out to left.*/
  top: 0;/*add this to make it position absolutely top to the parent*/
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
}

.block:hover .normal {
  background: #0084b4;
}

.block:hover .hover {
  margin-right: 0;
  right: 150px;/*add this to make it slide to left on hover*/
  transform-origin: top;
  /*
 animation-name: balance;
 animation-duration: 1.5s;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 animation-delay: 110ms;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-direction: alternate;
 */
  animation: balance 1.5s ease-in-out 110ms 1 alternate;
}

@keyframes balance {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  15% {
    margin-top: 0;
    transform: rotateX(-50deg);
  }
  30% {
    margin-top: 0;
    transform: rotateX(50deg);
  }
  45% {
    margin-top: 0;
    transform: rotateX(-30deg);
  }
  60% {
    margin-top: 0;
    transform: rotateX(30deg);
  }
  75% {
    margin-top: 0;
    transform: rotateX(-30deg);
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: 0;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="normal">
    <span>Follow me...</span>
  </div>
  <a target="_BLANK" class="hover" href="http://twitter.com/benoitboucart" title="My twitter profile">
  on Twitter
 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You for the reply, but that not what I really wants, I wanted to just slide out without using 'balance' as the animation is rotation, I just require slide out.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the animation from the `.block:hover .hover` part and should just slide it out. However, you might need to give it a fixed width.

```
.block .hover {
  background: #00aced;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 110px; /* to wrap the words, you can change it according to your design*/
  right: 0px;/*add this to make it position absolutely right to the parent so that it can slide out to left.*/
  top: 0;/*add this to make it position absolutely top to the parent*/
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
}
.block:hover .hover {
      margin-right: 0;
      right: 150px;/*add this to make it slide to left on hover*/
      transform-origin: top;
    }
```

Comment: Thank @umair, but that not what i really want, I want is one of the examples that i gotten from the web: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vRjJZE .It slide out when user hover.